# Ajax call not working

Tags: template, layout, controllers, ajax, 404-page

I'm trying to call a .phtml via an ajax call and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835146/using-basic-ajax-calls-within-magento) example on stackoverflow but I'm either missing some aspect or just doing it wrong.
When the ajax runs it gets a 404 and I did try to view it directly through the browser and it could not find it. Based on this I assume some aspect of the file structure that I set up is wrong but I can't figure what exactly.

I have controller located at local/CheckoutAjax/controllers/AjaxController.php

```
    <?php
    class Checkoutajax_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
          $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
      }
   }
```

In local/CheckoutAjax/etc/config.xml I have the following

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Checkoutajax>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Checkoutajax>
     </modules>
    <frontend>
    <routers>
    <Checkoutajax>
      <use>standard</use>
      <args>
          <module>Checkoutajax</module>
          <frontName>Checkoutajax</frontName>
      </args>
   </Checkoutajax>
   </routers>
   <layout>
     <updates>
       <checkoutajax>
         <file>checkoutajax.xml</file>
       </checkoutajax>
     </updates>
   </layout>
 </frontend>
    </config>
```

I have this in mytemplate/default/layout/checkoutajax.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout>
  <checkoutajax_ajax_index>
    <block type="checkout/checkoutajax" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkoutajax/index.phtml" />
 </checkoutajax_ajax_index>
 </layout>
```

and finally I have in mytemplate/default/template/checkoutajax/index.phtml

```
   <?php
   echo 'this is a test'
```

Finally this is the ajax call

```
   JQuery.ajax({
            url: "/checkoutajax/ajax/index",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
            $j('#results').html(data);
            document.getElementsByClassName('minicart-content')[0].style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some troubleshooting tips:

**Do you have a module registered in app/etc/modules?**

If not, it should be as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
             <active>true</active>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This module naming looks incorrect - it is expected to be separated with an underscore indicating namespace -- so, not this:

```
<module>Checkoutajax</module>
```

All modules are named as `Company_Module`, etc. Checkoutajax_AjaxController is then not a valid classname. Check your general PHP error log (or Apache logs) and you should see something to the effect of `class not exists`.

Change/update this to `ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax` or similar. All instances of Checkoutajax will need to be updated in the module xml definition.

The frontName also has issues, namely, it should be lowercase:

```
<frontName>Checkoutajax</frontName>
```

I'm not sure if Magento forces the lowercase on the routename.

**The updated code, then:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <Checkoutajax>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax</module>
          <frontName>checkoutajax</frontName>
        </args>
      </Checkoutajax>
    </routers>
    <layout>
     <updates>
       <checkoutajax>
         <file>checkoutajax.xml</file>
       </checkoutajax>
     </updates>
   </layout>
 </frontend>
</config>
```

And the controller:

```
<?php

class ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This is just a quick update to explain how routes/controllers/actions work in Magento. Let's say that this is your URL:

```
www.yourstore.com/checkoutajax/ajax/index
```

This represents three different entities:

- `checkoutajax` is the route name, also called `frontName` in the module definition XML
- `ajax` here represents the controller name. This controller file should be named AjaxController.php and located in the `/controllers` directory of your module.
- `index` represents the `indexAction` method.

So, to visualize:

```
www.yourstore.com/checkoutajax/ajax/index
---------route--------^
---------controller-------------^
---------action-----------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. You really explain a lot here. I'm just working through it at the minute. One quick question is to view it directly what does the url look like with the name change?

Comment: The URL stays the same as the route name isn't changed. I corrected it so that the lowercase matches the expected route name; also called `frontName` in the module definition. See my update for a quick ASCII representation of how routes, controllers, actions are represented in a URL.

Comment: I haven't managed to get it working yet. Is there anything else you can think of that I possibly left out.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your filename. Controller file should be named local/CheckoutAjax/controllers/AjaxController.php (without an s)

Comment: Apologies but that was a typo, I edited the question. Thanks for spotting it